# HTML/CSS, adding links to changing images

Tags: html, css

I am very new to this, so any help would be much appreciated.

I am in the process of learning to code and am using templates as guides, and I am using this slideshow template to create a slideshow. But the issue is that, for example, there are four images on the slideshow, but only one link button, linking to only one url. However, I want to code it so that I can link a different url to each of the four images. Below are the codes...

```html
{% if settings.show_block_lookbook %}
<div id="lookbook-section" class="section-full lookbook-section">

  <div class="lookbook-wrapper">
    <div class="lookbook-text">
      <div class="lookbook-container">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="lb-text">
            {% assign lbText1 = settings.block_lookbook_text_1 %}
            {% assign lbText2 = settings.block_lookbook_text_2 %}
            {% assign lbText3 = settings.block_lookbook_text_3 %}
            {% assign lbText4 = settings.block_lookbook_text_4 %}
            {% assign lbLink = settings.block_lookbook_link_1 %}         

            {% if lbText1 != blank %}<h3>{{ lbText1}}</h3>{% endif %}

            <div class="bg-slider-arrows">
              <span class="button-prev no-border"></span>
              <span class="button-next no-border"></span>  
            </div>

            {% if lbText2 != blank %}<h2>{{ lbText2 }}</h2>{% endif %}

            {% if lbText3 != blank %}<p>{{ lbText3 }}</p>{% endif %}

            {% if lbText4 != blank %}<a href="{{ lbLink }}" class="btn btn-custom btn-lb">{{ lbText4 }}</a>{% endif %}            
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="lookbook-bg">
    {% for i in (1..4) %}
      {% assign newShow = 'block_lookbook_img_' | append: i %}

      {% if settings[newShow] %}
        {% assign newImage = 'block_lookbook_img_' | append: i %}

        <div class="lookbook-item">
          <img src = "{{ newImage | append: '.jpg' | asset_url}}" alt="" />
        </div>

      {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</div>
{% endif %}
```

Simply said, what are the codes to put in if I want to make it so that I can add in a different url for each images. I have tried and tried but to no avail, so if someone can help with code samples, it would be much appreciated...

Comment: Read several times, not sure if the question is explicit here, it's really hard to understand what do you want. Do you want someone to write code for you, or what?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes, basically need help with writing code in so that I can add a different url to each image. Because right now the code only provides one link button linking to one url, with the images changing behind. So I basically need someone to provide the code so that I can link different url to each image...

Comment: @Luciano What have you tried to link each different url to an image? SO isn't really a place to get someone to write code for you.

Comment: A recommendation: It looks like you are using Angular JS, which is a framework.  I suggest you learn JavaScript instead.  Even if you stay with Angular JS, templates don't help you learn all that much.  They can help you to see how some particular code works together, but making your own code from scratch will help you learn so much more.  If you try making a slideshow from scratch, you'll have to make all the parts - the slides, the buttons that control the slides, a list of things that happen when someone clicks a button... with templates it is all just given to you.